# Flashing NodeMCU on ESP32

Tags: nodemcu, esp32

ESP8266 and ESP32 noob here. I bought a couple of [ESP32 modules](https://www.banggood.com/Wemos-TTGO-ESP32-Dev-Module-WiFi-Bluetooth-4MB-Flash-p-1181331.html) and I'm trying to install NodeMCU on them (they came with just some sample code).

I created a firmware image using the cloud builder and tried to flash it to the device (later on, I built it myself too, same result). After some experimentation I found that the bootloader expects the firmware to start at 0x1000 in the flash, instead of 0x0000 (I read the original flash content to confirm that), so I flashed the firmware at 0x1000. I can confirm using `read_flash` (or other methods) that the firmware has been flashed correctly. But when I connect to the serial port to see what the output is, I get this at the beginning:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0x00
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x01,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x04
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x260513e7,len:0
load:0x46007200,len:65534
1162 mmu set 00010000, pos 00010000
load:0x65920020,len:-491131
1162 mmu set 00020000, pos 00020000
1162 mmu set 00030000, pos 00030000
1162 mmu set 00040000, pos 00040000
1162 mmu set 00050000, pos 00050000
1162 mmu set 00060000, pos 00060000
1162 mmu set 00070000, pos 00070000
1162 mmu set 00080000, pos 00080000
1162 mmu set 00090000, pos 00090000
1162 mmu set 000a0000, pos 000a0000
1162 mmu set 000b0000, pos 000b0000
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

And after that this looping over and over again:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0x00
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x01,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x04
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x260513e7,len:0
load:0x46007200,len:65534
1162 mmu set 00010000, pos 00010000
load:0x65920020,len:-491131
1162 mmu set 00020000, pos 00020000
1162 mmu set 00030000, pos 00030000
1162 mmu set 00040000, pos 00040000
1162 mmu set 00050000, pos 00050000
1162 mmu set 00060000, pos 00060000
1162 mmu set 00070000, pos 00070000
1162 mmu set 00080000, pos 00080000
1162 mmu set 00090000, pos 00090000
1162 mmu set 000a0000, pos 000a0000
1162 mmu set 000b0000, pos 000b0000
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

At this point I'm quite lost in what could possibly be wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update: I succesfully flashed micropython (build for ESP32) on the device. That makes me think that the NodeMCU image I'm using is not good for ESP32 (but only ESP8266?).

Comment: Well... that really is the problem; I found that there's a separate branch for ESP32 [here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/en/build/)

I will post more info here if/when I manage to build it, just in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit into https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Yes, for ESP32 you need to use the dedicated branch. Good you found our documentation on this.

Comment: I agree this should be closed, but I don't think it's off topic. The mere fact that it took me several hours of googling could mean that this information will be useful to someone else. It's not entirely apparent that ESP8266 code will not work on ESP32 (not to noobs in this area like me).

Comment: It's off-topic as far as Stack Overflow is concerned if you read its definition - not my choice. I agree we could probably do more to make it clear that only the ESP32 branch fits onto an ESP32.

Comment: The root of my confusion is on https://nodemcu-build.com - at the bottom, there is an "affiliate" link to an ESP32 board on from China. I'd expect that images generated by the website will run on a product that is endorsed by the website.

Comment: @Marcel Stor It is not at all clear to me how the information about what is or is not on topic applies to this question. A question how to get a program into an SBC seems to be about programming and can also be answered in a concrete and helpful fashion. Please elaborate, and you may prevent that I make the same mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately - the solution is to use esp32 branch of nodemcu, as indicated in my comment above. The standard branch only works on ESP8266.